# Save value of id onchange() option in select box

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I need help I am trying to make a dependent select option, the problem is that I need to save the id value (career.id) of the first select in a variable in the component.ts

HTML

```
<td>
    <select [disabled]="flagAsignaturasCupo" 
            [(ngModel)]="carrera.id" class="form-control"
            id="carrera" name="carrera" required>
       <option value="0" selected>SELECCIONE UNA CARRERA</option>
       <option value="{{carrera.id}}" *ngFor="let carrera of carrerasdocente" class="small">{{ carrera.descripcion }}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

I need to save the run value.id of my previous selection in a variable and use it in the getSignatura to use it in parameters and the second select option works for me

Component.ts

```
getAsignaturasDocente () {
         const parameters =
         '? user_id =' + this.user.id
         + '& carrera_id =' + *** variable_that I need ***
         this.spinner.show();
         this.service.get('teachers/subjects' + parameters) .subscribe (
             response => {
                 this.asignaturasdocente = response['asignaturasdocente '];
                 this.spinner.hide ();
             },
             error => {
                 this.spinner.hide ();
             });
     }
```

Comment: Do I have it correct that when ever a new item is selected you want to know what the last selected item was? If so have you considered saving the selection each time it changes so when a new selection comes along you have the previous plus the new?

Answer (score 1):

You go on ngModelChange() on select tag like this :

Component.ts

```
getAsignaturasDocente (carreraId) {
     const parameters =
     '? user_id =' + this.user.id
     + '& carreraId =' + *** variable_that I need ***
     this.spinner.show();
     this.service.get('teachers/subjects' + parameters) .subscribe (
         response => {
             this.asignaturasdocente = response['asignaturasdocente '];
             this.spinner.hide ();
         },
         error => {
             this.spinner.hide ();
         });
 }
```

look at the code i change your carrera_id to carreraId but u can use carrera_id.

HTML :

```
<td>
<select [disabled]="flagAsignaturasCupo" 
        [(ngModel)]="carrera.id" class="form-control"
         (ngModelChange)="getAsignaturasDocente(carrera.id)"
        id="carrera" name="carrera" required>
   <option value="0" selected>SELECCIONE UNA CARRERA</option>
   <option value="{{carrera.id}}" *ngFor="let carrera of carrerasdocente" 
   class="small">{{ carrera.descripcion }}</option>
</select>
```

i use ngModelChange() because you use the ngModel for binding data so you can use ngModelChange ().